# Event Listener for Web XR

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, webxr

In the Web VR API there was an event listener for entering/exiting VR display;

```
window.addEventListener('vrdisplaypresentchange', function() {
//do something
}
```

Is there an equivalent for the Web XR API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really sure why it was downvoted (twice!).

The WebXR specs define a few events:

https://www.w3.org/TR/webxr/#event-types

As you can see there, there is a `visibilitychange` event (https://www.w3.org/TR/webxr/#eventdef-xrsession-visibilitychange) that might be helpful, but it really depends on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Yes, I agree with the down voting....tough crowd.  Thank you for answering.  I have tried the visibilitychange type;

Comment: I have tried  `visibilitychange` on different targets (window, document, navigator), unsuccessful.  From the document link above, looks like the target has to be session.   If I am adding my event listeners at  `init()`, there is no session.  Maybe my original question should be; is there an event listener for `WebXRManager.isPresenting:true`

Comment: Once you started a session, you know that it has started. afterwards you attach event listeners to the session to know when it stopped or changed.